# How do I create a recycle view row item as seen in this image?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a layout as seen in this image (the middle one), I am close to doing this but whenever I create a new post they are displayed from the bottom of each other. I would like it to be displayed as seen in the attachment from left to right I am not sure why its displaying like this, some help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/defaultproficpic"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePicture"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbImageView"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/thumb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOptions"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbImageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="book title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookPriceTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:text="Price of book"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:text="Author of book"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bookPriceTv"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bookPriceTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookPriceTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookCondition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:text="Condition of book"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bookAuthor"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bookAuthor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookAuthor" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This might help you [Android-GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView)

Answer (score 0):

Create this type of view we have used GridLayoutManager to show data in rows and columns

Replace LinearLayoutManager to GrideViewManager

Like This

```
//first parameter is context and second is number of column
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    adapter.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Check these link for more detail

[GrideLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

[GrideLayoutManager 1](https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)

[GrideLayoutManager 2](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html)